# Is there anyway I can measure the lux level (illuminance level) on a surface?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lighting

I am trying to design a lighting experiment using Unity. I have different types of lighting in a scene and now I need to know the illuminance level (lux level) on a surface in an environment that I have designed. Is there any way that I can do that? or any plug-ins that I can use?
I am not using HDRP but I realized it uses physical light units, though I am still not sure if it means I can get an illuminance value on a surface using that either. Should I switch to HDRP?

I will be grateful if anyone could help me, I am new to this. Thanks!